# does storing Data in ViewState slows down the page load?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have stored my dataset in the View State(because i need to filter the data on different client clicks and show the data) but i feel like the page loading is taking a lot of time, even a checbox checked event(with AutoPostback) which does not have any code to execute is taking almost 2-3 seconds.

is this just because of the view state data, if so are there any alternatives for which i can achieve my tasks? and i need the data to be shown quicky on client events so i have been using the view state. any work around would help.

Answer (score 1):

As @Tushar mentioned above, ViewState is not the place you want to be storing large amounts of data.  It's really only meant to preserve the state of controls between round trips, and it can really lead to poor app performance.

Instead you should look into the following server managed options:

**Application State** - Used for storing data that is shared between all users. Uses server memory.

**Session State** - Used for storing data specific to a user's session. Also uses server memory.  Data can be persisted through app restarts, as well throughout a web-garden or server-farm. More info from MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1hkazw7.aspx

The biggest cons of those methods are memory management, as both options consume server memory, and keep data until there is either a restart of some sorts, or until the session is dropped.  Thus, these methods don't always scale well.

Also, here is an MSDN article discussing the various .net methods of state management, with pros and cons for each method :

A third option is to implement a caching strategy by either using the [.NET caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997357%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) libraries, building your own and/or using 3rd party caching servers/libraries. The benefit to using cache is that you have the data automatically expire after any given specified amount of time.  However, complexities are introduced when working in a web-garden or server-farm environment.

The biggest thing to remember, is that any of the strategies mentioned above will require some planning and consideration in regards to managing/sharing the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you're storing a large amount of data in ViewState, you'll notice performance issues.  Although ViewState is really meant for a "this page only" and Session is meant for "this session", you'll reach a limit with ViewState size where the Session is ultimately much better for performance.

It's worth noting that you might be having some other type of issue, not just an issue with the ViewState (i.e. your database query may be taking a long time and could possibly be cached).

Answer (score 0):

The ViewState makes the page slightly larger due to the extra data embedded in the page's HTML to hold the serialized ViewState.  Whether that extra size will cause *load* problems depends on the connection speed, and on the size of the view state relative to the rest of the page.

The ViewState is sent back to the server with each HTTP request (so including your AutoPostback).  Again, whether that causes a noticeable performance issue depends on the view state size and the connection speed.

On a broadband(ish) connection with the amount of ViewState data one would find in a typical page, you would not see 2-3 seconds *additional* processing time.

**Diagnosing**

Use the developer tools in your browser (in IE, press F12).  You can monitor web requests including the exact header and body sent and received.  You can also see the timing for each HTTP request.  If the ViewState is not huge (not more than 1-2K perhaps) and your connection speed is not excessively slow, that is not your culprit.

**Alternatives**

You can hold state entirely server-side, or put any state items that are large entirely on the server.  You can use Ajax requests to process page events that depend on that state.

Comment: thanks eric. what do you mean by holding data on server side? you mean to put the data in an hidden field?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading data from a data-source multiple times, only do it one time.  The other answers talk about accessing the data.  I have run into instances where I load the data every time I do a post-back.

```
string myString;

public string MyString
{
    get
    {
        // If there is already data in "myString", do not load it again!
        if (this.ViewState["myData"] == null)
        {
             // Load data one time
             this.ViewState["myData"] = "Hello";
        }
        return this.ViewState["myData"] as string;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How much ViewState slows down your page depends upon have much view state you have. I've inherited pages that generated over a megabyte of viewstate and seen the web server spend 10 seconds just processing the view state. If you don't want to rewrite your application and you need the large amount of view state, you need to investigate alternate strategies for saving / restoring view state. Saving ViewState to a database or even a plain file is much faster -- don't have to stream viewstate to/from client on each request.

Best strategy is to avoid viewstate in the first place though.

Just thought I should add, some controls are simply ViewState pigs, some grids are just terrible for viewstate consumption.

Comment: thanks gary, but see for every request i dont want to get the datat from the data source, for this reason i have been keeping my data ina vieww state so that i can filter the data from the view state and render it accordingly. if there are any other ways of doing it other that view state that would help.

Comment: That is exactly what I meant by alternate strategy for viewstate storage. See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20310/Save-ViewState-on-the-File-System for an example of using a disk file -- guaranteed much faster the streaming over the internet (or even localhost base64)

Answer (score 0):

You can view the source of your page and get the `ViewState` value and use the online `ViewState decoder` at below *url* to check how much large are the values stored in your ViewState field for your pages:

http://ignatu.co.uk/ViewStateDecoder.aspx

If you find your viewstate is *having* large stored values then you should find alternatives for storing your `Dataset`.

Anyways, you should avoid putting the Dataset into your ViewState.